# Should I switch the transfomer input or output?

Tags: transformer

I am installing a remote receiver switch into my outdoor lighting circuits and wonder should I leave the 230-12volt transformer (500va) permanently supplied & install the switch module on the 12 volt output or would switching the 230 volt input be best.

Comment: I use both.   Bluetooth to switch low V and for other lights Digital timer for AC. I also converted all my 8W Tungsten lamps to 4W LEDs on my Schlumberger outdoor transformer with 30A Diode Bridge and 50mF  cap with low ESR for DC.

Answer (score 1):

I would aim to switch the high voltage. A 500 VA transformer will waste power even when unloaded.

> No-load losses are caused by the magnetizing current needed to energize the core of the transformer, and do not vary according to the loading on the transformer. They are constant and occur 24 hours a day, 365 days a year, regardless of the load, hence the term no-load losses. They can be categorized into five components: hysteresis losses in the core laminations, eddy current losses in the core laminations, I 2R losses due to no-load current, stray eddy current losses in core clamps, bolts and other core components, and dielectric losses. Hysteresis losses and eddy current losses contribute over 99% of the no-load losses, while stray eddy current, dielectric losses, and I 2R losses due to no-load current are small and consequently often neglected. Thinner lamination of the core steel reduces eddy current losses.
>
> The biggest contributor to no-load losses is hysteresis losses. Hysteresis losses come from the molecules in the core laminations resisting being magnetized and demagnetized by the alternating magnetic field. This resistance by the molecules causes friction that results in heat. The Greek word, hysteresis, means "to lag" and refers to the fact that the magnetic flux lags behind the magnetic force. Choice of size and type of core material reduces hysteresis losses.
>
> Source: [Copper.org](https://www.copper.org/environment/sustainable-energy/transformers/education/trans_losses.html).

For example, if the 500 VA transformer no-load losses are 5% (and I have no idea if that's reasonable) then continuous power waste is 25 W. There are 8760 hours in a year so energy loss is 8760 h x 0.025 kW = 219 kWh*. You can save energy in all the off hours by switching the primary.

Do the right thing!

Reference:

- [Transformer Losses and Efficiency](http://www.electricaleasy.com/2014/04/transformer-losses-and-efficiency.html).
- [Carroll-Meynell](http://carroll-meynell.com/cms/page/view/page_id/26/).

* To generate 219 kWh of electrical energy with a 40% efficient oil or coal-powered generating station would use about 50 kg of fuel (based on 10 kWh per kilo of oil).

Answer (score 0):

Check the voltage ratings oh your input. Check the operational voltage range. If it has an inbuilt adapter to convert 230 to 12, you don't need the transformer to do the job for it.

Answer (score 0):

My answer would be switch the lower voltage / DC side, as I *think* it's less susceptible to arcing and therefore safer... but I think there's going to be some varied opinions here. The flip side of that argument is that you're going to be switching smaller currents at the higher voltage, but my gut says voltage is the primary variable when deciding what to switch in power circuits. I'm prepared to be down-voted by people better versed in these matters, though. It's really somewhat more of a question for an electrician than an electrical engineer...

Comment: You're switching an inductive load at the input side so you need an appropriate switching arrangement to deal with the current peaks from that which are much higher than the running load.

Answer (score 0):

I would switch the mains side. As pointed out already, this will prevent losses when the circuit is idle. However you should ensure that your switching circuit is adequate to deal with a 500VA inductive load. Due to the inrush current and the tendency of an inductor to sustain the flow of current when voltage is removed (that's what inductors like to do) it must be rated to carry these currents and/or use strategies to reduce them. A relay (the simplest solution) should have an inductive load rating (which will be much lower than its resistive load rating) and you should still have a generous margin with that. 500VA at 230V is little over 2 amps, so look for a 4 or 5A inductive load rated relay. If your switch circuit is electronic (e.g. triac) you'll need to likewise rate it for these momentary switching currents.

You can reduce these currents with considered design. This application note for instance

http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/2f/f7/75/f5/9d/3d/44/04/CD00003867.pdf/files/CD00003867.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00003867.pdf

discusses switching (with a triac) and is a good read. It shows how you should

(a) switch at the peak of the mains cycle (when the current flow due to the magnetic field on the inductor is crossing the zero point)

(b) always switch on at the opposite polarity to the last switch off. This is due to the remnant magnetisation of the core.

If you can do that, you can seriously reduce the surges. The application note actually shows the measured currents on a 200VA 12V lighting transformer.

But that's probably more than you want to get into, so just use a nice big hunky relay with a nice big inductive load rating on the live connection of the transformer. Switch the coil of that with your electronics.

Also make sure you install a normal switch for safety isolation purposes on the transformer supply. A relay or electronic switch does not provide safety isolation (for when you want to work on the transformer or the loads it supplies).